# Passing html text content into javascript functions, multiple sentence can be highlighted

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, function, parameters

I would like to pass the text as a variable value to the javascript  so as to highlight the relevent content.

for example: 
in html:

```
<p id="sentence" >a paragraph </p>
<p id="content"> And this here  is inside a paragraph , about paragliders. happy ending.</p>
```

in css:

```
.highlighted { background:yellow }
```

in javascript:

```
  var word= document.getElementById('sentence').value;
  var root=document.getElementById('content').value;

function highlightWord(root,word){


  textNodesUnder(root).forEach(highlightWords);

  function textNodesUnder(root){
    var walk=document.createTreeWalker(root,NodeFilter.SHOW_TEXT,null,false),
        text=[], node;
    while(node=walk.nextNode()) text.push(node);
    return text;
  }

  function highlightWords(n){
    for (var i; (i=n.nodeValue.indexOf(word,i)) > -1; n=after){
      var after = n.splitText(i+word.length);
      var highlighted = n.splitText(i);
      var span = document.createElement('span');
      span.className = 'highlighted';
      span.appendChild(highlighted);
      after.parentNode.insertBefore(span,after);
    }
  }
}
```

however, it cannot work. 
How to make it work to show the result as the picture shows?????
[image]

Thanks to @vijayP answer. the code works.[image]

I have the other issue with how to loop the function so that multiple sentence can be highlighted??? Thanks a lot!

update: in the html/jsp:
https://jsfiddle.net/bob90937/2yw3s376/   how to improve this. so that multiple sentence can be highlighted?????

Comment: Why do you reinvert the wheel? [mark.js](https://markjs.io)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modified your code a bit. Also used JQuery for easily reading paragraphs values:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  
  var wordText = $('#sentence').text();
  var rootText = $('#content').text();
  var rootNode = document.getElementById('content');

  highlightWord(rootText, wordText);

  function highlightWord(rootText, wordText) {

    textNodesUnder(rootNode).forEach(highlightWords);

    function textNodesUnder(rootNode) {
      var walk = document.createTreeWalker(rootNode, NodeFilter.SHOW_TEXT, null, false);
      var text = [],
        node;
      while (node = walk.nextNode()) text.push(node);

      return text;
    }

    function highlightWords(n) {
      for (var i;
        (i = n.nodeValue.indexOf(wordText, i)) > -1; n = after) {
        var after = n.splitText(i + wordText.length);
        var highlighted = n.splitText(i);
        var span = document.createElement('span');
        span.className = 'highlighted';
        span.appendChild(highlighted);
        after.parentNode.insertBefore(span, after);
      }
    }
  }

});
```

```css
.highlighted {
  background: yellow
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p id="sentence">a paragraph</p>
<p id="content">And this here is inside a paragraph , about paragliders. happy ending.</p>
```

Updated Fiddle Link:

https://jsfiddle.net/2yw3s376/3/

Code for dealing with `<table>` structure:

**HTML:**

```
<tr>
  <td class="sentence">a paragraph</td>
  <td class="content">And this here is inside a paragraph , about paragliders.happy ending.</td>
<tr>
```

used `class` instead of `id`; as we can't have duplicate ids in DOM

**JS Code:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  //loop through all sentence one by one
  $(".sentence").each(function() {
    var parentTR = $(this).closest("tr");
    var wordText = $(this).text();
    var rootNode = parentTR.find('.content')[0];
    var rootText = $(rootNode).text();

    highlightWord(rootText, wordText, rootNode);

  })


  function highlightWord(rootText, wordText, rootNode) {

    textNodesUnder(rootNode).forEach(highlightWords);

    function textNodesUnder(rootNode) {
      var walk = document.createTreeWalker(rootNode, NodeFilter.SHOW_TEXT, null, false);
      var text = [],
        node;
      while (node = walk.nextNode()) text.push(node);

      return text;
    }

    function highlightWords(n) {
      for (var i;
        (i = n.nodeValue.indexOf(wordText, i)) > -1; n = after) {
        var after = n.splitText(i + wordText.length);
        var highlighted = n.splitText(i);
        var span = document.createElement('span');
        span.className = 'highlighted';
        span.appendChild(highlighted);
        after.parentNode.insertBefore(span, after);
      }
    }
  }

});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! it works. can i ask one more question about how to do the loop to highlight the multiple sentence. the current code can only highlight the only one sentence. I edit my question.

Comment: @bob90937 - could you please modify your HTML code to exactly show the multiple sentences.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the below code :

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function () {
        var mytext = $("#content").html();
        var find = $("#sentence").html();
        console.log(mytext + find);
        mytext=mytext.replace(new RegExp(find,"g"), "<span class='highlighted'>"+find+"</span>");
        $("#output").html(mytext);
})

</script>


<p id="sentence" >a paragraph </p>
<p id="content"> And this here  is inside a paragraph , about paragliders. happy ending.</p>

<p id="output"></p>
```

And CSS goes here..

```
.highlighted { background:yellow }
```